# Mongoose ObjectId : Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am having difficulty creating my own ObjectId. I have two models:

```
const TableSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({ 
  .... 
  chairs: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ChairModel}] 
  .... 
}) ;


const ChairSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({ 
 .... 
 table: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'TableModel} 
 .... 
 }) ;
```

This pattern works for me ever time, when ObjectId is generated by mongoose.

But when I generate a randomAlphaNum string:

```
let randomNum = makeRandom(24); //  1etdk0c86762e0fb12dptsli
let TableId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(randomNum);
```

I generate the error:

> Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a
>   string of 24 hex characters

How can I create a valid mongoose ObjectId from a simple alphaNumeric script generator?

Comment: You can pass it as a string. I had the same problem when I was trying to use firebase's uid as a value to _id in monodb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ObjectIds must be composed of valid Hex values (you have p, t and s). One option (I don't know which library are you using for makeRandom) is to restrict the characters set of makeRandom to 0-9 a-f.
Otherwise, if they are random you can let mongoose to generate ids for you:

```
let tableId = mongoose.Types.Objec‌​tId()
```